# Как взаимодействовать с API Telegram в обход блокировки?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Начал писать Telegram бота.
Сразу столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу получить ответ (видимо из-за блокировки РКН)

Попробовал прокси - не помогло - или я что-то не так настроил....

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли сейчас способы обойти блокировку и написать Telegram бота?

Comment: Непонятно, на каком языке написано и что попытались сделать.

Comment: Можете настроить vpn, есть бесплатные, настраиваются довольно просто, далее все запросы нормально проходят

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для обхода блокировки, нужно подключаться к SOCKS5 прокси:

```
/*** PHP CODE ***/
/****************/
$prxy       = 'http://94.130.223.179:1080'; // адрес:порт прокси
$prxy_auth = 'auth_user:auth_pass';       // логин:пароль для аутентификации
/****************/
$ch  = curl_init();
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXXXX&text=XXXXX"; // где XXXXX - ваши значения
curl_setopt_array ($ch, array(CURLOPT_URL => $url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true)); 
/********************* Код для подключения к прокси *********************/
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);  // тип прокси 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY,  $prxy);                 // ip, port прокси
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $prxy_auth);  // авторизация на прокси
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);                // отключение передачи заголовков в запросе 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);            // возврат результата в качестве строки
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);                      // использование простого HTTP POST
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);        // отмена проверки сертификата удаленным сервером
/***********************************************************************/
$result = curl_exec($ch);  // DIGITAL RESISTANCE!
curl_close($ch);
```

Не забудьте подставить рабочий прокси адрес ($prxy) и, если необходимо, данные для аутентификации ($prxy_auth), а также свой запрос ($url)

Answer (score 0):

В линуксе можно воспользоваться, например, `proxychains4`:

```
Usage:  proxychains4 -q -f config_file program_name [arguments]
    -q makes proxychains quiet - this overrides the config setting
    -f allows one to manually specify a configfile to use
    for example : proxychains telnet somehost.com
```

Эта программа заворачивает все попытки вашего скрипта выйти в интернет через прокси. В настройках `proxychains4` указываете список прокси, через которые ваш скрипт будет ходить в интернет.