# Как обойти блокировку API Telegram через VPN в Python?

Tags: python, telegram

Имеется приложение включающее в себя несколько ботов, для ВК, для Telegram, но при проверки для Telegram выдает вот это

> urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', 
>   ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал
>   существующее подключение', None, 10054, None)".

Как я понимаю это блокировка срабатывает. Как пустить трафик только этой части приложения через VPN?

Comment: Используйте VPN или размещайте бота на заграничном сервере.

Comment: А через какую библиотеку бот работает?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как взаимодействовать с API Telegram в обход блокировки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/817268/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-api-telegram-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Можно хостить на PythonAnywhere

Comment: *"Как пустить трафик только этой части приложения через <strike>VPN</strike>proxy"* Можно использовать [`opener`, который запросы через  прокси делает (заменить `urlopen()` на `opener.open()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/523568/23044)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще, я вам напомню, что для работы бота 24/7 сервер где он работает, должен быть всегда включен, ваш ПК так не может, самый простой способ обойти блокировку это поставить бота на хостинг, бесплатные это heroku и pythonanywhere второй чуть проще поэтому его и советую, он работает не в России а помоему в Америке, где РКН бессилен