# Ошибка 10054 при бездействии бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Бот нормально работает, но через какое то время бездействия появляется эта ошибка

('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение', None, 10054, None))

Comment: Чтобы из Вашего вопроса стало понятно хоть что-то, добавьте свой код.

Comment: Это связано с блокировкой telegram в РФ. [Как обойти блокировку API Telegram через VPN в Python?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/849086/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d1%83-api-telegram-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-vpn-%d0%b2-python)

Comment: @SergBocharov уже разблокировали https://habr.com/ru/news/t/507244/, поэтому - нет, не связано.

Comment: @mrEvgenX Тогда возможно автор использует прокси, который стоит сменить. А еще вероятнее при использовании прокси использует `http` вместо `htpps`